# How do I find the lowest value in the past 50 candles on mql5?

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

I would like to find out the lowest traded price in the past 50 candles. I've used the following code.

```
double Lowest_Low = iLowest(_Symbol,PERIOD_CURRENT,MODE_LOW,50,0);
```

I've tried using -50, but it does not give me the lowest price on the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the [iLowest](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/series/ilowest) function incorrectly. This function returns the **shift** of the lowest value over a specific number of bars. You need to combine it with [iLow](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/series/ilow) to get the value, as follows:

```
double Lowest_Low = iLow(NULL, 0, iLowest(NULL, 0, MODE_LOW, 50, 0));
```